# inline divs for horizontal scroll UI, second div is not at top

Tags: html, css

I have the following setup which results in a horizontal scrolling UI with different "pages".  Each page is the full width of the device/browser.  Everything seems okay, except that `#other` is not at the top of the screen. It looks more like this (if you are mid-scroll between the two pages):

[image]

Using Chrome's dev tools I have confirmed that the height of the element is correct. It's actually behind the footer and about 400 pixels "lower" than the left div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu-header"></div>
<div id="pageContainerContainer">
    <div id="pageContainer">
        <div id="home" class="page">Stuff here</div>
        <div id="other" class="page">Other things</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menu-footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu-header, #menu-footer {
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    height: 80px;
    z-index:50;
}
#menu-header { top: 0; }

#menu-footer { bottom: 0; }

#pageContainerContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    bottom: 80px;
    width: 100vw;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
#pageContainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 200vw;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.page {
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `position: relative` to the `.page` class fixed the issue.